# How to set global hook WH_CBT in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to create global WH_CBT hook using winapi. I create dll with this hook. When I using this
dll in other application ( this app load dll and start hook - let it name be abc.exe ) I can load that dll, get functions ( with hook and unhook ) and see the output, but only from that abc.exe's thread. I would like to see messages like HCBT_CREATEWND from other windows ( not only from abc.exe window ). I set the fourth arg in SetWindowsHookEx to 0, so I except to set the global hook.

In abc.h:

```
    HINSTANCE hDll;
    typedef void( * MYPROC )( void );
    MYPROC funHook, funUnhook;
```

In abc.exe window constructor (abc.cpp):

```
    hDll = LoadLibrary( L"probaHook" );

    if( hDll )
    {
        funHook =( MYPROC ) GetProcAddress( hDll, (LPCSTR) "hook" );
        funUnhook = ( MYPROC ) GetProcAddress( hDll, (LPCSTR) "unhook" );

        qDebug()<<funHook<<funUnhook;

        if( funHook )
        {
            funHook();
        }
    }
```

In abc.exe window destructor (abc.cpp):

```
    if( funUnhook )
    {
        funUnhook();
    }
    
    FreeLibrary( hDll );
```

In probahook.h ( file with dll declaration functions ):

```
#ifndef PROBAHOOK_H
#define PROBAHOOK_H

#include "probaHook_global.h"
#include "windows.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK cbtHookProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
extern "C" PROBAHOOK_EXPORT void hook( void );
extern "C" PROBAHOOK_EXPORT void unhook( void );
class PROBAHOOK_EXPORT ProbaHook
{
public:
    ProbaHook();
};

#endif // PROBAHOOK_H
```

In probaHook_global.h:

```
#ifndef PROBAHOOK_GLOBAL_H
#define PROBAHOOK_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(PROBAHOOK_LIBRARY)
#  define PROBAHOOK_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define PROBAHOOK_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // PROBAHOOK_GLOBAL_H
```

In probahook.cpp:

```
#include "probahook.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

HHOOK hhook = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK cbtHookProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if( code < 0 ) return CallNextHookEx( 0, code, wParam, lParam );
    qDebug()<<code;
    if( code == HCBT_CREATEWND )
    {
        QFile file(R"(C:\Users\tom\Desktop\def.txt)");
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
        file.write(QString::number(GetCurrentThreadId()).toStdString().c_str());
        file.write("\n");
        file.close();
        return 0;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx( 0, code, wParam, lParam );
}

ProbaHook::ProbaHook(){}


BOOLEAN APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    hInst = hModule;

    switch( ul_reason_for_call )
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void hook( void )
{
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, cbtHookProc, hInst, 0 );
}

void unhook(void)
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx( hhook );
}
```

The output from def.txt is:
17192
17192
17192
17192
17192
17192

17192 is my abc.exe thread. Of course when abc.exe is running I try open other windows.

qDebug() in cbtHookProc of course produce output like: 4,6,0, but only from abc.exe window.

Comment: Global hook DLLs are injected into each running process. So you need separate DLLs for hooking 32bit and 64bit processes. And does the injecting EXE have a message loop to handle the dispatching of hook calls? Depending on what you are using the CBT for, you might consider using `SetWinEventHook()`, which does not require DLL injection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see that my dll works, but only for my apps. When I run for example Acrobat Reader, VirtualBox, VLC media player, I don't see any lines in txt file ( which is only to check if I achieve what I want ). Of course I create injecting exe 32 too.